# What does ミラー and 光が飛んで mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning

Can anyone help me understand what ミラー(mirror) is referring to below and how it relates to 光が飛んで. Is this related at all to [白飛び](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/113080/meaning/m0u/)
or does it mean something else?

> よし、んじゃカメラはそこな。あとは小道具のセッティングだけど
> え？　もうやってくれたのか！　さすが頼りになる部員たちだぜ
> んじゃ、青空をバックに小鳥が飛ぶシーンから撮るぞ～
> そーそーそのアングル。けど、それだとちょっと**光が飛んで**んな……**ミラー**ある？

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have the right idea. 白飛び = overexposure, where the highlights can't be recovered by post-processing. 光が飛ぶ has the same meaning. (黒つぶれ is underexposure.)

ミラー in this case means a reflector to illuminate the scene, more commonly referred to as  レフ板 or リフレクター.